# Eclipse show Problems tab instead of Debug on error

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I make Eclipse always show the Problems tab (shown in image), rather than the Debug tab, when an error occurs? I find the Problems tab much more useful, and it is annoying to constantly have to switch from Debug to Problems every time there is an error.

[image]

I am using this version of eclipe:

clipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Build id: 20130919-0819

Comment: Not clear what you want. Do you want to display the Problems View in the Debug Perspective?

Comment: @Simulant I think I am in the normal perspective, the code window is above the window that I showed in the screenshot. Basically, whenever I click F11 to rebuild/run, if there are errors, that bottom window switches to Debug. I want it to stick to Problems, or ideally whatever tab I had last opened.

Comment: What abaout moving the debug (or the problem one) to a different part of the window ? Then, both of them should be visible.

Answer (score 8):

Op1: Go to **Window->Show View->Problems** or any other tabs you want eclipse to show

Op2: press **Alt+Shift+Q** to activate it

I hope my answer would help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a box a few tabs over next to your current output

You're currently on the tab "Problems" Try the one a few over named "Console"
that should fix it